# iPhone: How to get a UIImage from a url?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uiimage

How do you download an image and turn it into a UIImage?

Comment: I'm asking/answering my own question here because a Google search for this question yielded results that are no longer correct with the latest SDK.

Comment: This library will do all the web related stuff to create an image asynchronously from url for you:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
```

However, this isn't asynchronous.

Answer (score 15):

You should keep in mind that loading the image data with the sample code you've provided in your own answer will block the main thread until the download has completed. This is a useability no-no. The users of your app will think your app is unresponsive. If you want to download an image, prefer NSURLConnection to download it asynchronously in its own thread.

[Read the Apple documentation about async downloads with NSURLConnection.](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

When your download completes, you can then instantiate your UIImage from the data object:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (requestData)
    {
        self.image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:requestData] autorelease];
    }
}
```

Where `requestData` and `image` are instance variables of your containing class, and `image` is a retained property. Be sure to release `image` in the `dealloc` routine of the class, e.g. using `self.image=nil;`.

Comment: Excellent point.  I was just looking at this also: http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Comment: This is an absolute must. Here are a couple of classes that handle asynchronous UIImage loading and caching using blocks.  http://t.co/ovOn86KG

Comment: Andrew - using your block-based approach, is the resulting UIImage being returned on a background thread?  If so, I think that when assigning that to an UIImageView it would need to be explicitly done so on the main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread - yes?

Comment: Take a look at the couple of libraries in my answer. I have been using it in a project and works great.

Answer (score 5):

It is true that Asynchronous loading is a must, but you can also achieve that with a background call if you just need a simple solution.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImage) withObject:nil];

- (void)loadImage
{
   NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://.../....jpg"];
   NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
   if (image)
   {
       // Success use the image
       ...
   }
   else
   {
       // Failed (load an error image?)
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can load an image in a `UIImageView` from a URL without blocking the UI thread simply using the `dispatch_async`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [myImageView setImage:image];
            });
        });
```

The first `dispatch_async` is used to load the image from the URL in background (without blocking the UI). The second `dispatch_async` is used to actually inject the image just loaded in the `UIImageView`. Please, note that the second `dispatch_async` is designed to work on the **main thread** (the UI thread) that is, indeed, the thread used to update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good example here using blocks: http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/uiimage-from-url-%E2%80%93-simplified-using-blocks/

Answer (score 1):

Based on @philfreo's answer I created a NSURL Extension in swift using BrightFutures (for the asynchronous callback:

```
extension NSURL{
    func downloadImage() -> Future<UIImage, NSError>{

        let promise = Promise<UIImage, NSError>()

        Queue.global.async{
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: self){
                if let image = UIImage(data: data){
                    promise.success(image)
                    return
                }
            }
            promise.failure(NSError())
        }

        return promise.future
    }
}
```

This then lets me do:

```
import BrightFutures

let someURL = ...;
someURL.downloadImage().onSuccess{ image in
  // Do something with the UIImage
}
```

### Update

A simple synchronous extension could look like this:

```
extension NSURL{
    func downloadImage() -> UIImage?{
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: self){
            return UIImage(data: data){
        }
    return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what @philfreo's answer looks like in swift:

```
let urlString = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
let image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

This works in a playground:

[image]